# Ruby on rails edit_to is redirecting when should open modal

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 buttons for editing a task, one on tablelist page, that works perfectly opening a form modal to edit, the other one is in the popover that open on the calendar that isn't working properly, it's redirecting instead of opening a modal to edit, if i put the button on the page it works, but on the popover doesn't. To solve that i want my code to open the form_modal to edit at the same time as the popover, but with display:none, and then became display: block when i click on edit button, how can i do that?

Button on the _popover.html.erb:

```
      <%= link_to edit_task_path(task, redirect_to: tasks_url(view: params[:view])), remote: true, class: 'btn btn-outline-primary' do %>
        <span class="fas fa-pen" aria-hidden="true"></span> Editar
      <% end %>

Button on the _table_list.html.erb:
              <%= link_to icon('fas', 'pen'), edit_task_path(task, redirect_to: tasks_url(view: params[:view])), title: 'Editar', remote: true, class: "px-1" %>
```

tasks.js:

```
$('.tasks.new, .tasks.edit').ready(function() {
  $('#task_scheduled_time').mask('99:99');
});

$('.tasks.index').ready(function() {
  const url = '/tasks';
  const new_task_url = $('#new_task_url').val();
  const calendar_view_url = $('#calendar_view_url').val();
  const table_view_url = $('#table_view_url').val();
  const calendar_container = document.getElementById('calendar')
  const default_date_field = $('#default_date');
  const default_view_field = $('#default_view');
  const table_container = $('#table-list-container');
  const form_search = $('#form-search');

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap4',
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    minTime: '06:00:00',
    maxTime: '22:00:00',
    allDaySlot: false,
    nowIndicator: true,
    displayEventEnd: true,
    navLinks: true,
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    customButtons: {
      table: {
        bootstrapFontAwesome: 'fas fa-list',
        click: function() {
          var url = new URL(window.location.href);
          url.searchParams.set('view', 'table');
          window.location.href = url.href;
        }
      },
      calendar: {
        bootstrapFontAwesome: 'fas fa-calendar',
        click: function() {
          var url = new URL(window.location.href);
          url.searchParams.set('view', 'calendar');
          window.location.href = url.href;
        }
      }
    },
    header: {
      left: 'table,calendar prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month'
    },
    events: { url },
    dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
      $.get(new_task_url, { date: date.format() })
    },
    eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) { 
      $.get(event.url);
      return false;
    },
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.complete-task', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    const link = $(this)
    $("#tasks-modal").modal("show");
    $("#tasks-confirm").off("click").on("click", function () {
      $.ajax({
        url: link.attr('href'),
        type: 'PATCH',
        data: {
          authenticity_token: $('[name="csrf-token"]')[0].content,
        }
      })
      window.location = '/tasks';
      toastr.info('Atividade concluída com sucesso')
    })
  })
});

$(document).on('click', '.close-popover', function () {
  $(this).closest(".popover").remove();
});

$(document).ready(function(){

  $.validator.addMethod("hour", function(value, element) {
    const regex = /^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/;
    return regex.test(value);
  }, "Horário incorreto");

  time_validation = function() {
    let selectedTime = $('.validation').val();
    selectedTime = formatHoursMinutes(selectedTime)
    if(!selectedTime) {
      $("#task-alert-modal").modal("show")
      $('#task_scheduled_time').val('');
    }
  }

  function formatHoursMinutes(value) {
    const regex = /^(\d{1,2}):?(\d{1,2})?$/;
    const match = value.match(regex);
  
    if (match) {
      const hours = match[1] ? match[1].padStart(2, '0') : '00';
      const minutes = match[2] ? match[2].padStart(2, '0') : '00';
      if (parseInt(hours) > 23 || parseInt(minutes) > 59) {
        return null;
      }
      const formattedValue = `${hours}:${minutes}`;

      if (formattedValue.length !== 5) {
        return null;
      }
      return formattedValue;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
});
```

where the popover is opened Index.html.erb:

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <%= link_to 'Visão Geral', dashboard_path, class: 'breadcrumb-item' %>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Atividades</li>
  </ol>
</nav>

<%= hidden_field_tag :default_view, 'agendaWeek' %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :default_date, l(params[:default_date], format: '%m/%d/%Y') %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :new_task_url, new_task_path(redirect_to: tasks_path(view: params[:view], group_by: params[:group_by])) %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :calendar_view_url, tasks_path(view: 'calendar', group_by: params[:group_by]) %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :table_view_url, tasks_path(view: 'table', group_by: params[:group_by]) %>

<div class="card mb-3 border-0">
  <% unless params[:view] == 'calendar' %>
    <div class="row justify-content-between">
      <div class="col-auto ms-3 my-3">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <%= link_to raw("<i class='fas fa-list'></i>"), tasks_path(view: 'table', group_by: params[:group_by]), class: 'fc-calendar-button btn btn-outline-primary' %>
          <%= link_to raw("<i class='fas fa-calendar'></i>"), tasks_path(view: 'calendar', group_by: params[:group_by]), class: 'fc-calendar-button btn btn-outline-primary' %>
        </div>
        <%= link_to 'Nova', new_task_path(redirect_to: tasks_path(view: params[:view], group_by: params[:group_by])), class: 'btn btn-outline-primary', remote: true %>
      </div>
      <%= form_tag tasks_path, method: :get, class: "d-flex flex-row align-items-center flex-wrap col-2 me-3" do %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :view, 'table' %>
        <%= select_tag(:group_by, options_for_select(@groupings, params[:group_by]), {class: "form-control auto-submit w-100"}) %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <% if params[:view] == 'calendar' %>
    <div class="p-3 mb-2">
      <div id="calendar">
      </div>
    </div>
  <% else %>
    <div id="table-list">
      <%= render partial: 'table_list', locals: { tasks: @tasks } %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
<%= render partial: "shared/confirm", locals: {id: "tasks"}%>
<%= render partial: "shared/alert", locals: { id: "task-alert", modal_message: "Horário Inválido" } %>
```

code that opens the popover show.js.erb:

```
var task = $("[href='/tasks/<%= @task.id %>.js']");

$('body').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).parents('.popover').length == 0)
    task.popover('hide');
  $('body').off('click');
});

$(document).on("click", ".popover .close-popover" , function(){
  $(this).parents(".popover").popover('hide');
});

task.popover(
  {
    trigger: 'click',
    content: `<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'tasks/popover', locals: {task: @task}) %>`,
    html: true,
    placement: 'auto',
    container: 'body',
    viewport: {
      selector: 'body',
      padding: 0
    }
  }
);
task.popover('show');
$(".task-title").css("background-color", "<%=@task.task_category.color%>")
task.on('shown.bs.popover', function (e) {
  $('.popover-task>.close').on('click', function(){
    task.popover('hide');
  });
  $('.popover-task .btn').on('click', function(e){
    task.popover('hide');
    return true;
  })
});
```

edit.js.erb:

```
$('#modal-window').html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "form_modal", 
  locals: {
    task: @task,
    responsibles: @responsibles,
    relatables: @relatables,
    categories: @categories
  }
) %>');
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
$('#task_scheduled_time').mask('00:00');
$('#task-form').validate({
  rules: {
    "task[scheduled_time]": {
      hour: "_"
    },
    "task[relatable_string]": {
      required: true,
    },
    "task[task_category_id]": {
      required: true,
    },
    "task[duration]": {
      digits: true,
    }
  },
  messages: {
    "task[scheduled_time]": {
      hour: "Horário incorreto"
    },
  },
  errorPlacement: function (err, elem) {
    if ($(elem).hasClass('place-error-last')) {
      elem.closest('.col, .form-group').append(err)
    } else err.insertAfter(elem) 
  }
});

$('#timezone-link').on('click', function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('#timezone-select').show();
});

$('#modal-window').modal('show');

tasks_controller.rb:
  before_action :set_task, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :complete]
  before_action :set_options, only: [:new, :edit]
  before_action :set_redirect_path, only: [:create, :update]
  before_action :permissions

  def complete
    if @task.update_attribute(:status, "COMPLETED")
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to params[:redirect_to] || tasks_path, notice: "Atividade concluída com sucesso" }
        format.js { }
      end
    else
      flash[:error] = @task.errors.full_messages.join(". ")
      render "shared/rollback"
    end
  end

  def search_relatables
    @grouped_relatables = [
      Contact.where({ company: current_company, deleted_at: nil }).by_name(params[:query]).map { |x| { id: x.id, name: x.name, class: "Contact" } },
      Deal.by_company_id(current_company.id).where("title like ?", "%#{params[:query]}%").map { |x| { id: x.id, name: x.title, class: "Deal" } }
    ]

@relatable_count = 0

@grouped_relatables.each do |relatable|
  @relatable_count += relatable.length
end
  end

  def index
    params[:default_date] = params[:default_date].present? ?
      Date.parse(params[:default_date]) :
      Date.today
    params[:group_by] ||= "task_category_html"
    params[:view] ||= "calendar"

@groupings = [
  ["Categorias", "task_category_html"],
  ["Responsável", "responsible_avatar_link"],
  ["Relacionado", "relatable_name"],
  ["Data", "scheduled_date"],
]

@tasks = Task.by_company_id(current_company.id)
             .by_deal_privacy(current_user)
             .not_deleted

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { @tasks = @tasks.group_by_attribute(params[:group_by]) }
  format.js { @tasks = @tasks.group_by_attribute(params[:group_by]) }
  format.json do
    params[:start] = params[:start].blank? ? Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month : Date.parse(params[:start])
    params[:end] = params[:end].blank? ? Time.zone.now.end_of_month : Date.parse(params[:end])
    @tasks = @tasks.where(scheduled_date: params[:start]..params[:end])
  end
end

  end

  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { }
      format.js { }
    end
  end

  def new
    if current_company.has_booking_available?
      @task = Task.new
      @date_time = DateTime.parse(params[:date]) if params[:date].present?
    else
      redirect_to warning_path(origin: "tasks")
    end
  end

  def edit
  end
```

Calendar that opens the popover fullcalendar.js:

```
DayGrid.prototype.showSegPopover = function (row, col, moreLink, segs) {
        var _this = this;
        var view = this.view;
        var moreWrap = moreLink.parent(); // the <div> wrapper around the <a>
        var topEl; // the element we want to match the top coordinate of
        var options;
        if (this.rowCnt === 1) {
            topEl = view.el; // will cause the popover to cover any sort of header
        }
        else {
            topEl = this.rowEls.eq(row); // will align with top of row
        }
        options = {
            className: 'fc-more-popover ' + view.calendar.theme.getClass('popover'),
            content: this.renderSegPopoverContent(row, col, segs),
            parentEl: view.el,
            top: topEl.offset().top,
            autoHide: true,
            viewportConstrain: this.opt('popoverViewportConstrain'),
            hide: function () {
                // kill everything when the popover is hidden
                // notify events to be removed
                if (_this.popoverSegs) {
                    _this.triggerBeforeEventSegsDestroyed(_this.popoverSegs);
                }
                _this.segPopover.removeElement();
                _this.segPopover = null;
                _this.popoverSegs = null;
            }
        };
        // Determine horizontal coordinate.
        // We use the moreWrap instead of the <td> to avoid border confusion.
        if (this.isRTL) {
            options.right = moreWrap.offset().left + moreWrap.outerWidth() + 1; // +1 to be over cell border
        }
        else {
            options.left = moreWrap.offset().left - 1; // -1 to be over cell border
        }
        this.segPopover = new Popover_1.default(options);
        this.segPopover.show();
        // the popover doesn't live within the grid's container element, and thus won't get the event
        // delegated-handlers for free. attach event-related handlers to the popover.
        this.bindAllSegHandlersToEl(this.segPopover.el);
        this.triggerAfterEventSegsRendered(segs);
    };
    // Builds the inner DOM contents of the segment popover
    DayGrid.prototype.renderSegPopoverContent = function (row, col, segs) {
        var view = this.view;
        var theme = view.calendar.theme;
        var title = this.getCellDate(row, col).format(this.opt('dayPopoverFormat'));
        var content = $('<div class="fc-header ' + theme.getClass('popoverHeader') + '">' +
            '<span class="fc-close ' + theme.getIconClass('close') + '"></span>' +
            '<span class="fc-title">' +
            util_1.htmlEscape(title) +
            '</span>' +
            '<div class="fc-clear"/>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="fc-body ' + theme.getClass('popoverContent') + '">' +
            '<div class="fc-event-container"></div>' +
            '</div>');
        var segContainer = content.find('.fc-event-container');
        var i;
        // render each seg's `el` and only return the visible segs
        segs = this.eventRenderer.renderFgSegEls(segs, true); // disableResizing=true
        this.popoverSegs = segs;
        for (i = 0; i < segs.length; i++) {
            // because segments in the popover are not part of a grid coordinate system, provide a hint to any
            // grids that want to do drag-n-drop about which cell it came from
            this.hitsNeeded();
            segs[i].hit = this.getCellHit(row, col);
            this.hitsNotNeeded();
            segContainer.append(segs[i].el);
        }
        return content;
    };
```

Comment: I fear no one is going to read through all the code you posted. Can you please boil it down to the pertinent parts?

Comment: It's possible that the event is not being captured correctly because of how it's being triggered within the popover. Since the popover content is dynamic, you might need to use delegated event handlers. For example, instead of directly binding the click event to the edit button, you should delegate it from a static parent element: